# Cannot resize shotcut window

Tags: 20.04, window

I started using Ubuntu and installed Shotcut as my video editor. However the window is too big and gets outside of my screen and I cannot resize or maximize it, is this a known issue or something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: One thing to try is to press Alt and use the mouse to move the window. You may be able to move the edge of the window into reach, so you can resize it to fit.

Comment: But I cannot shrink it more, it is stuck at a size and the option of maximizing is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link: https://forum.shotcut.org/t/shotcut-resize-maximize-when-timeline-is-showing/3044
I need to close the timeline section, maximize it. and reopen the timeline section.